# Does FusedLocationProviderClient use all available data?

Tags: location, kalman-filter, fusedlocationproviderapi

I want to estimate the device location as accurately as possible with sparse GPS access, so I was thinking that I want to use a Kalman filter with the GPS, acc, gyro, magneto and perhaps also pressure data, all sampling at maximum frequency. FusedLocationProviderClient seems to do something like this and return the position with getCurrentLocation, but does anyone have more insight into how it works, and if it is an optimal solution?

K